# How to show Snackbar in android app supporting for all device

Tags: java, android, xml, android-xml

I am going to use android SnackBar in my app instead of Toast. Help me to add SnackBar in my app.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this link,

https://androidbycode.wordpress.com/2015/06/06/material-design-snackbar-using-the-design-support-library/

You can show Snackbar with the help of Design Library.